# Drupal: changes on test site affect live site

Tags: php, session, drupal, drupal-7, session-cookies

I've set up a drupal site and copied it to a subdomain for testing:

- live site: www.mydrupalsamplesite.com
- test site: test.mydrupalsamplesite.com

If I sign in to both sites at the same time (same browser), changes on one site affect the other site. For example: If I sign out on the test site, I also get logged off on the live site.

I didn't find anything related to my problem. My best guess is that it might be a cookie issue because both sites are on the same domain.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you didn't change the **settings.php** file, which means your two sites are linked to the same database !

Comment: `If I sign out on the test site, I also get logged off on the live site.` Well yeah, they use the same session data more than likely. I think this is pretty normal behavior

Comment: I copied the database and changed the settings.php. So the databases are separated.